# Run Project - doesn't recognize custom project arguments - Java - Netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm following a tutorial which asks me to create this simple calculator class that is supposed to use arguments that I entered > set project configuration > customize > arguments. I entered numbers in the arguments line. When I run the class it gives me the println and sum 0.0. When I run the project it says build successful but gives me nothing. Why doesn't it println and recognize the arguments I entered when I Run Project?

here is the class

```
public class calc {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        float sum = 0;
        for (String argument : arguments) {
            sum = sum + Float.parseFloat(argument);
        }
        System.out.println("Those numbers add up to " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you make a screenshot from the textbox or the window where you entered your numbers?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the path you entered to write your arguments. Maybe these are different.

You have to right-click on your project and open **Properties** right at the bottom. A window should open where you can choose **Run**. There you can see **Arguments:** followed by a textbox where you can put them. They're space seperated

---

Just two things about your code:

1. The name of your class should start with a capital letter.
2. The line where you actually *sum* can be written like `sum += Float.parseFloat(argument);`

---

**EDIT**

Okay now I found your way to the arguments and it's the same.

Could you make a screenshot from that window please? Because your code and my arguments work totally fine

Comment: did that work with you in netbeans 8.2 or 8.1 @Pascal Schneider?

Comment: I figured out what happened. Under Set Project Configuration - Customize, netbeans automatically filled in the Main class using a different class. When I changed it and ran the project, everything worked. Thanks